# Dynamically apply background color to af:column header as inlinestyle

Tags: html, css, jsf, oracle-adf

I have a requirement to dynamically apply a background color to a `af:column` header.
I have tried the below options:

1. Applying `background-color` through the `headerClass` property of `af:column` is working fine. But as it is defined in a CSS file I am not able to change dynamically.
2. Creating header facet of `af:column` and applying `background-color` as an inline style but the color is not applied to the entire cell as there is some `padding` on all four sides of `th` element.

**Code:**

```
<f:facet name="header">
    <af:outputFormatted value="column_1" id="pt_of1" inlineStyle="background-color:Blue;"/>
</f:facet>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Inline styles are always cumbersome with complex components. Use a class and create a full css selector and style in a stylesheet tag dynamicall.

Comment: That what kukeltje says. Give it a class and change classes with javascript (jQuery) when needed

Answer (score 0):

You can change headerClass attribute dynamically:   headerClass="#{myBean.caseA? 'headerClassA': 'headerClassB'}"
All you need is two classes in your CSS file: headerClassA and headerClassB